# How to get data from textFieldDidEndEditing to save to Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to get the inputted text from recipeName, servingsNumber, prepTime and cookTime to save to fb.

I know this is close to where I need to be. I am need some help with my save function. I need to assign the textField.text in sendToFirebase() I am able to print out the inputted text into the console and I was able to get it to save a document to FB but the entry was null. What am I missing? I feel like it is here in my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class AddRecipeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var data = [RecipeData]()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
    var objRecipe = RecipeData.init()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPressed))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "RecipeNameCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "recipeName")
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "ServingSizeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "servings")
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "PrepTimeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "prep")
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "CookTimeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cook")
    }
    
    func sendToFirebase() {
        do {
            let recipeName = objRecipe.recipeName
            let servings = objRecipe.servingsNumber
            let prep = objRecipe.prepTime
            let cook = objRecipe.cookTime
            let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
            let id = objRecipe.id
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(objRecipe)
            let dictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
            db.collection("Recipe").document(objRecipe.id).setData(dictionary)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    @objc func cancelPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        sendToFirebase()
    }
}
```

---

```
extension AddRecipeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeName", for: indexPath) as! RecipeNameCell
            cell.textField.delegate = self
            cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "servings", for: indexPath) as! ServingSizeTableViewCell
            cell.textField.delegate = self
            cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prep", for: indexPath) as! PrepTimeTableViewCell
            cell.textField.delegate = self
            cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 3{
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cook", for: indexPath) as! CookTimeTableViewCell
            cell.textField.delegate = self
            cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeName", for: indexPath) as! RecipeNameCell
            return cell
        }
    }
}

extension AddRecipeViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        switch textField.tag {
            
        case 0:
            let recipeName = textField.text!
            print(recipeName)
            objRecipe.recipeName = textField.text!
//            sendToFirebase() // Send to firebase
        case 1:
            
            let servingSize = textField.text!
            print(servingSize)
            objRecipe.servingsNumber = textField.text!
//            sendToFirebase() // Send to firebase
        case 2:
            let prepTime = textField.text!
            print(prepTime)
            objRecipe.prepTime = textField.text!
//            sendToFirebase() // Send to firebase
        case 3:
            let cookTime = textField.text!
            print(cookTime)
            objRecipe.cookTime = textField.text!
//            sendToFirebase() // Send to firebase
        default: break
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct RecipeData: Codable {
    var user: String?
    var recipeName: String?
    var ingredientsText: String?
    var directionsText: String?
    var servingsNumber: String?
    var prepTime: String?
    var cookTime: String?
    var image: String?
    let id = UUID().uuidString
}
```

---

```
class RecipeNameCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var name: String?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textField.placeholder = "Recipe Name..."
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
func saveData(text: String) {
    if let recipeName = recipeNameTextField.text,
       let addedIngredients = ingredientsTextField.text,
       let directionsText = directionsTextField.text,
       let servingsNum = numServingLabel.text,
       let image = imageView.image,
       let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
        
        let newRecipeRef = db.collection(D.FStore.collectionName).document(id)
        newRecipeRef.setData([
            D.FStore.recipeTextField: recipeName,
            D.FStore.ingredientsText: addedIngredients,
            D.FStore.directionsText: directionsText,
            D.FStore.numberServings: servingsNum,
            D.FStore.userField: user,
            D.FStore.id: id,
            D.FStore.image: image,
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document added with ID:\(newRecipeRef)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeScreenViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var logout: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var add: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var data = [RecipeData]()
    var recipeNamed: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "RecipeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
        func loadRecipeNames() {
        db.collection("Recipe")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        if let user = data["User"] as? String,
                           let recipeNameLabels = data["Recipe Name"] as? String,
                           let prep = data["Prep Time"] as? String,
                           let cook = data["Cook Time"] as? String,
                           let servings = data["Servings"] as? String
                        {
                            let newRecipe = RecipeData(user: user, recipeName: recipeNameLabels, servingsNumber: servings, prepTime: prep, cookTime: cook)
                            self.data.append(newRecipe)
  
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.table.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    @IBAction func logoutPress(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func addRecipePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "add", sender: self)
    }
    
}

extension HomeScreenViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let data = data[indexPath.row]
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeCell
        
        cell.recipeNameLabel.text = data.recipeName
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire the `sendToFirebase()` function:

```
extension AddRecipeViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        switch textField.tag {  
        case 0:
            let recipeName = textField.text!
            print(recipeName)
            objRecipe.recipeName = textField.text!

            sendToFirebase() // Send to firebase
        case 1:
            
            let servingSize = textField.text!
            print(servingSize)
            objRecipe.servingsNumber = textField.text!
            sendToFirebase()

        case 2:
            let prepTime = textField.text!
            print(prepTime)
            objRecipe.prepTime = textField.text!
            sendToFirebase()

        case 3:
            let cookTime = textField.text!
            print(cookTime)
            objRecipe.cookTime = textField.text!
            sendToFirebase()

        default: break
        }
    }
    
}
```

`sendToFirebase()` function:

```
func sendToFirebase() {
    
    let recipeName = objRecipe.recipeName
    let servings = objRecipe.servingsNumber
    let prep = objRecipe.prepTime
    let cook = objRecipe.cookTime
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
    let newRecipeRef = db.collection("Recipe").document(objRecipe.id)
    newRecipeRef.setData([
        "Recipe Name" : recipeName ?? "Empty",
        "Serving #" : servings ?? "Empty",
        "Prep Time" : prep ?? "Empty",
        "Cook Time" : cook ?? "Empty",
        "User" : user ?? "No email provided",
    ])
    { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document added with ID:\(newRecipeRef)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241109/discussion-on-answer-by-excitedmicrobe-how-to-get-data-from-textfielddidendediti).